# Add or remove PHP string depending on value

Tags: php, pdo

I want to add or remove php strings/arrays from the following code :

```
$params = array_merge([$pstatus, $_POST["minimum_price"], $_POST["maximum_price"]],$branddata);
```

If the `$branddata` is still there when the string is NULL, the SQL will show error. So if the `$branddata` is NULL/empty, I want to remove `$branddata` from `$params`.
If `$branddata` has value `$branddata` should be in  `$params` otherwise it should not be there.

This is for PDO prepared statement function. It wont work with empty `IN()` value.

I was able to do  the following only!

```
$base_sql = "SELECT %s FROM filter WHERE product_status = ?";
$query = sprintf($base_sql, "*")." AND price BETWEEN ? AND ?";
if(!empty($branddata)){
    $query .= "AND brand IN($brand) ";  
}
```

How can I add or remove `$branddata` from `$params` ?

Comment: What is the error you receive? How is `$brand` built? This seems like the issue might be higher up in your application.

Comment: @user3783243, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63484292

Comment: Check if it's empty before adding it to params?

Comment: @ankr, that is where I want help. if it is empty, I dont want to add it to $params

Comment: You're already checking if it's empty where you expand your query. Add it to $params the same place.

Comment: @ankr, thank you for your comment. But I dont know how to do that. Can you please post an example as an answer ? you can see the larger picture at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63484292

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_filter` to remove null or empty values from an array.

```php
$params = [1, '', null];
print_r($params);

/*
Array
(
[0] => 1
[1] =>
[2] =>
)
*/

$params = array_filter($params);
print_r($params);

/*
Array
(
    [0] => 1
)
*/
```

It will unfortunately take out all empty parameters, including zero and the empty string. If you only want null values removed, you can add a callback to that function to check just for null.

```php
$params = array_filter($params, function ($v){return $v !== null;});
```

*edit*

Without fully knowing what is in `$branddata` except that you say that it can be null/empty, I have to take a little bit of a guess.

First, if `$branddata` is actually null, `array_merge` will freak out, and I would fix that with a simple null coalescing operator, `$branddata ?? []`.

Here's a sample that does a little more:

```php
$branddata = ['', null];
$params = array_filter(array_merge(['alpha', 'beta'], $branddata ?? []));
```

This spits out an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => alpha
    [1] => beta
)
```

*edit*

The very literal version that should work for you is:

```php
$params = array_filter(array_merge([$pstatus, $_POST["minimum_price"], $_POST["maximum_price"]], $branddata ?? []));
```

Comment: just one more question, if I wanted to add more data, like $branddata1 and $branddata2, how can I add that ? just by separating comma ?

Comment: You should think first, whether an empty element have to be added to the resulting array at all. May be you won't need no code remove it